How can I get a refund from the Mytrip travel agency?
Exactly six months ago, I booked flights through Mytrip. Unfortunately, the flight was canceled. While the airline has already refunded Mytrip, I still haven't received any of my money back.
I have spoken to 50 representatives from Mytrip, all giving the same responses: "Your refund request has been prioritized" or "We have escalated your refund request to the support team/refund team." They promise a supervisor will email/call back, but no one ever does. It’s frustrating as the communication is so bad and you have to keep sending new ones to continue the conversation.
According to their website, my refund, already paid by the airline, has not been processed into my account. Mytrip initially claimed it would take a week to process the refund back in February. Now, four months later, I still have not received my money.
In total, it has been nearly six months since the flight was cancelled, and I still haven't received any refunds. It feels like Mytrip is intentionally delaying so I will give up.
I am disgusted by how I have been treated. No one should have their hard-earned money stolen. If this matter isn't resolved immediately, my next step will be to contact the small claims court to file a legal complaint. How can I get my refund?


Have you contacted your bank to ask them to dispute the card payment you originally made when you booked?

It's been a while and they said they can not process it now.

This is one of the reasons we consistently recommend against booking via online travel agents and prefer booking directly with the airlines. Also we've seen quite a few similar stories about mytrip around here. Where are you based? Legal claims may be complex if they have to cross borders...

I live in England.


How can I get my refund?

Try the following:

use a free complaints resolution service like Resolver
contact a consumer rights champion / journalist such as MoneySavingExpert or The Guardian (Consumer desk: money@theguardian.com), they may be willing to take up your issue with mytrip
mytrip is part of the etraveli group. Email the group’s CEO mathias.hedlund@gmail.com and mathias.hedlund@etraveligroup.com with your complaint, mentioning other routes such as MSE that you’ll be contacting to publicise mytrip’s abysmal customer service.


Thank you so much

The BBC has consumer and travel problems shows, might help as well.
